# Make close voting easier on the iOS app by reordering post action links

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, user-interface, ios-app, user-experience

On the iPhone app in portrait (at least on an iPhone 6 or smaller, it's probably not an issue plus size models) the "close" link is hidden behind the "more" button:

> [image]

On the site however the "close" link comes before "flag":

> [image]

Changing the order for consistency with the site would have the added benefit of a smoother user experience when close voting from the app. Not only would this save on an extra tap and UI to get to the close screen but would show you the number of existing close votes without having to actively go looking for it (as the site does).

It is possible to close by using the flagging dialog, which gets around the issue of extra taps, but that still hides the current vote count and probably isn't known by a lot of users. Flagging should be used as a last-resort option so using the flag dialog as a vote-by-proxy is encouraging the wrong behaviour and confusing.

Comment: This fits with flagging to call in a human exception handler being the tool of last choice. Hence it should not be as easy to find as the close button.

Comment: @PolyGeo If a user can close vote, they are already a human exception handler. By that logic, the flag button should be hidden as that's what can be used to call in moderators.

Comment: @Catija a close vote is not an exception, that is routine functionality (so should be readily accessible) while flagging to trigger the intervention of a moderator should be not be used by anyone who has the close vote privilege in preference to that.  The flag button should be harder to find than the close button.

Comment: I'm pretty sure PolyGeo is agreeing with you, @Catija.

Comment: Edit/Share buttons also might be need to reorder for consistency. Reducing space between buttons or draw only icon or split icons and text into 2 lines are another ways to show all of them without need to extra tap.